# Adding dynamic_date_formats to existing index - Do I need to re-ingest my data?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elastic, and there is an existing index which has not detected a date field in the existing data (queries like `dateField: [1900-01-01 TO 1901-01-01]` do not fetch expected results). I looked at the index mapping and I would like to add a dynamic_data_formats field to the same, as it is missing.

My question is: Will doing a PUT and adding the dynamic_date_formats to my index mappings make such queries work? Or will I have to take additional steps like re-ingest my data?
Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the mapping of an existing index using the [PUT Mapping api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) , but it wont be appicable to existing documents(its called addictive changes) after updating the API, you have to re-index all the data if you want existing doc to have this date values.

Answer (score 1):

Editing the dynamic date formats won't have an effect on existing documents -- they (as all parts of the mapping) reflect the current state of the index but, if changed, apply only to future additions to your index.

You'll need to refresh your data -- or re-ingest it (officially called re-index).